# ZipArchive::close() returns false even with all permissions in folder

Tags: php, filesystems, php-ziparchive

Everything works fine on localhost, but when I try to get this script to work on server I couldn't. I tried to change permission of root and uploads (where uploaded images are and where .zip files should be created) to `777` (I know it's not safe, but I just tried to test because it worked on localhost) but it doesn't. I also don't get any additional errors, and error reporintg (`E_ALL`) is turned on in `php.ini`. Directories are also created normally in that folder via `mkdir()` function.

Here is the function for zipping folders:

```
function Zip($source, $destination)
{

    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}

if (Zip($folder.$archiveName."/", $folder.$archiveName.".zip")) {
    echo "Done.";
    rrmdir($folder.$archiveName."/");
} else {
    addError("Error while trying to compress files.");
}
```

I also tried to write out the error message:

```
if ($zip->close()) {
    echo "Done.";
}
else {
    echo $zip->getStatusString();
}
```

But it doesn't write out anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved - I localized problem with debugging and realized that zip extension wasn't loaded. In case you encounter this problem too (site is deployed on [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/)) and you're using Debian or derivative just install `php7.0-zip` package:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause for ZipArchive::close to return false can be caused by file permissions on any of the files being added to the archive.

If PHP can't open the file added to the archive, `ZipArchive::addFile()` will return true, but when `ZipArchive::close()` is called you will get:

> "Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Can't open file: Permission denied"

More details in this comment from the PHP Manual:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php#101605

> Beware: calling $zip->addFile() on a file that doesn't exist will
> succeed and return TRUE, delaying the failure until you make the final
> $zip->close() call, which will return FALSE and potentially leave you
> scratching your head.
>
> If you're adding multiple files to a zip and your $zip->close() call
> is returning FALSE, ensure that all the files you added actually
> exist.
>
> It's also a good idea to check each file with file_exists() or
> is_readable() before calling $zip->addFile() on it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).